# My computer checks disk drives but won't boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, dvd

I have a desktop with a DVD player, a DVD writer, and two hard disk drives installed.
On the master hard disk I have installed Ubuntu Linux with GRUB.

For the past two days  I've been having problems with booting. When I switch the computer on, it checks each drive (first DVD player, then DVD writer, then the disk drives) and after a short delay, instead of going to the GRUB boot menu it repeats the four steps above forever.

Sometimes, after repeating the check for a while (something like 20 times), it finally opens the GRUB boot screen and boots normally. After that the computer can work normally for hours.

My first idea was that the DVD player or one of the hard drives could be broken. So I tried unplugging each of them separately, but the problem is still there.

So, could you give me a hint as to what I should check next? Can it be a controller problem or a motherboard problem? If you need more information about the drive models I will try to find the computer's handbook (I normally get this information from the BIOS but I cannot without booting).

Comment: Not really a solution, but maybe a workaround: Try to disable booting from DVD in your BIOS/UEFI/whatever. It is normally accessible before booting begins by pressing F12, Del, or some other particular key.

Comment: I had thought about that but the system won't get as far as checking the keyboard. So I do not get a chance to go to the BIOS configuration (it is the DEL key on my system).

Comment: disconnect 1 hard drive at a time and see if that changes anything and report the changes.

Comment: Even if drives are broken this shouldn't be happening. No clue what the problem is, though, sorry.

Comment: I have personally seen computers freeze for >10 minutes or more due to bad hard drives and other behaviors.  The BIOS checks to make sure the drives are accessible and if not they will keep on waiting, some have a reasonable 30 second wait and some never give up.  It repeats the 4 steps over and over because the BIOS can not detect a valid boot device.  So one of your hard drives is probably going bad and working some of the time and failing the rest.

Comment: @cybernard: I have tried disconnecting the drives one at a time and I see no difference. I have disconnected all of them and still it does not get to check the keyboard. I heard a click from the motherboard (the same click it does each time it checks the drives when the drives are connected).

Comment: If you can get it to run check the voltages with speedfan or other hardware monitoring utility. If you have a volt meter and feel confident you can do it safely you can check the voltages that way also.  The tolerance for any voltage is +/- 5%.  On any 4 pin molex connector the middle 2 wires are grounds.